# In 2 Corinthians 7:3 what does Paul mean by "you are in our hearts to die together and to live together"?

Tags: 2-corinthians

> NASB 2 Corinthians 7:3 I do not speak to condemn you, for I have said before that **you are in our hearts to die together and to live together**.

It sounds kind of romantic and tragic. What does he mean and was it specific to these Corinthians?

Answer (score 2):

Paul was contrasting his ministry to them compared to false teachers who were on the "taking" side, not willing to die for them, really not living with them spiritually.  They were the wolves in sheep's clothing, while Paul and company were willing to give their everything for the Church at Corinth (and all others).

Editing to meet requirements: My initial support for any opinion of a given interpretation of scripture (in this case English-KJV) is context before and after, then seeking companion scripture(s) with similar context.

2 Cor 6- 7:2 lays the framework for 7:3.  It declares the high price Paul pays to deliver truth to that area heavily influenced by idolatry and many false religious doctrines, a nest of deceivers. 2 Corinthians 6:8-9 (KJV) 
"8  By honour and dishonour, by evil report and good report: as deceivers, and yet true; 
9  As unknown, and yet well known; as dying, and, behold, we live; as chastened, and not killed;" is to me a fair summary of that chapter. 2 Cor 3 is a strong background for his plea not to become corrupted by teachers demanding Paul to present documentation (letters) of qualification as practiced deceiver to deceiver as he described.

In short Paul was persecuted nearly to death often but lived on willing to live with the Corinthians in all tribulations, or die with them.

A very familiar pivotal passage is support for Paul's statement in 2 Cor 7:3. 
Romans 8:10-14 (KJV) 
"10  And if Christ be in you, the body is dead because of sin; but the Spirit is life because of righteousness. 
11  But if the Spirit of him that raised up Jesus from the dead dwell in you, he that raised up Christ from the dead shall also quicken your mortal bodies by his Spirit that dwelleth in you. 
12  Therefore, brethren, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live after the flesh. 
13  For if ye live after the flesh, ye shall die: but if ye through the Spirit do mortify the deeds of the body, ye shall live. 
14  For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, they are the sons of God."

Paul promised the Corinthians the blessings of departing from corruptions and avoiding deceivers by way of two deaths, one dying to the flesh and sin, and the other death of the flesh in the midst of persecution for the sake of Christ. He was doing that daily as we all should strive toward more and more. Each Christian must be so anti sin as to be as though like a physically dead man is to life in the flesh, detesting sin practices unto death if necessary.  Paul was ready to finish his days on earth but held on for the sake of the Church. My support for that attitude is prevalent in the epistles of Paul.

Comment: Thank you for the response and welcome to the site. What you have provided is, to my mind, simply a thesis. That is, you provided your interpretation but made no effort to demonstrate that what you say is so by providing appropriate references. Can you please provide evidence that what you opine is accurate? It is in fact a site requirement. Thanks.